# how to avoid scalling issues on inputs in mobile html?

Tags: html, css, mobile, sass

I got an issue with this, my website looks good in mobile and in pc the issue arises when you try to type, for some reason the website "zooms out" and makes everything very small, how could I avoid this?

It seems to me as some kind of scaling bug but I cannot replicate it on other websites so I don't understand what is wrong

the images on my site are svg and png, but do to security measures they are set as a background (so that common users cannot right click them and download them), hence why I just created a div with a certain height and width following the image ratio

SASS:

```
.content .contact{
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    .layout{
        background-image: url('../'+$assets-path+'img/sobre.png');
        background-size: cover;
        $ratio:161.73/188.41;//h/w
        $height: 80vh;
        $drop-shadow-margin: 7.066/188.41;//shadow/width

        padding-top: 1%;
        box-sizing: border-box; 

        height: $height * $ratio;
        width: $height;
        margin-left: $height * $ratio * $drop-shadow-margin;

        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;

        form{
            margin-right: 4%;
            margin-top: 5.6%;
            box-sizing: border-box; 

            width: 88.2%;
            height: 55%;
            
            align-self: flex-start;

            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            // background-color: blue;

            input{
                margin-bottom: 1%;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                width: 70%;

                border-radius: 6px;
                border: 1px lightgray solid;
                padding: 2%;

                &:focus{
                    outline: none !important;
                    border-radius: 6px;
                    border: 1px lightblue solid;
                }
            }

            textarea{
                margin-bottom: 3%;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                width: 70%;
                height: 35%;
                resize: none;
                border-radius: 6px;
                border: 1px lightgray solid;
                padding: 2%;
                &:focus{
                    outline: none !important;
                    border-radius: 6px;
                    border: 1px lightblue solid;
                }
            }

            button{
                background-color: #2A9D8F;
                border:none;
                width: 40%;
                height: 10%;
                border-radius: 10px;
                color: white;
                outline: none !important;
                transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
                font-size: 65%;
                &:hover{
                    background-color: #264653;
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width:600px){
        .layout{
            $ratio:161.73/188.41;//h/w
            $width: 80vw;
            $drop-shadow-margin: 7.066/188.41;//shadow/width
            align-self: flex-end;

            margin-bottom: 10vh;

            height: $width * $ratio;
            width: $width;
            margin-left: $width * $ratio * $drop-shadow-margin;

            

            form{
                background: #f7f7f7;
                height: 50vh;
                margin-bottom: 33%;
                margin-top:0;
                align-self: flex-end;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="welcome" id="welcome">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <h3>Subtitle</h3>
        <h3>Sutbtitle</h3>
        <h2>Slogan</h2>
        <a class="down" href="#who"><div class="arrow"></div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="who" id="who">
        <div class="page">
            <div class="text">
                <h1>¿Quiénes somos?</h1>
                <p>Lore</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="courses" id="courses">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="course">
                <h1>Curso de Alfabetización Digital</h1>
                <p class="left">El próximo genio de la oficina serás tu</p>
                <p>Hoy comienzas tu curso</p>
                <div class="links">
                    <a href="#">Más información</a>
                    <a href="#">Inscríbete ya</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="phone"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact" id="contact">
        <div class="layout">
            <form action="">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Correo (e-mail)" required>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Asunto" required>
                <textarea placeholder="Cuerpo" required></textarea>
                <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Here's a screen shot of the issue]

Comment: I am assuming your problem is with the ratio calculation. Create sand box and will look into it. And btw did you add `Viewport` meta?

Comment: Yes I did, I have actually tinkered with it to no avail, but you may be onto something... I'll check it out too